# c# Generic overloaded method dispatching ambiguous

Tags: c#, methods, generics, overloading, dispatch

I just hit a situation where a method dispatch was ambiguous and wondered if anyone could explain on what basis the compiler (.NET 4.0.30319) chooses what overload to call

```
interface IfaceA
{

}

interface IfaceB<T>
{
    void Add(IfaceA a);
    T Add(T t);
}

class ConcreteA : IfaceA
{

}

class abstract BaseClassB<T> : IfaceB<T>
{
    public virtual T Add(T t) { ... }
    public virtual void Add(IfaceA a) { ... }
}

class ConcreteB : BaseClassB<IfaceA>
{
    // does not override one of the relevant methods
}

void code()  
{
    var concreteB = new ConcreteB();

    // it will call void Add(IfaceA a)
    concreteB.Add(new ConcreteA());
}
```

In any case, why does the compiler not warn me or even why does it compile?
Thank you very much for any answers.

Comment: What happens if you expect a return value from the call, i.e. `var result = concreteB.Add(new ConcreteA());`?

Comment: Becuase your Generic Method has a return "Type T" and the other one is of type "void". The compiler can differentiate between them.

Comment: the compiler will complain that `var` cannot be used, because he cannot assign void to implicitly typed variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows the rules in section 7.5.3.2 of the [C# 4 specification](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=dfbf523c-f98c-4804-afbd-459e846b268e&displaylang=en) ("Better function member").

First (well, after seeing that both methods are *applicable*) we need to check the conversions from argument types to parameter types. In this case it's reasonably simple because there's only one argument. Neither conversion of argument type to parameter type is "better" because both are converting from `ConcreteA` to `IfaceA`. It therefore moves on to the next set of criteria, including this:

> Otherwise, if MP has more specific
>   parameter types than MQ, then MP is
>   better than MQ. Let {R1, R2, …, RN}
>   and {S1, S2, …, SN} represent the
>   uninstantiated and unexpanded
>   parameter types of MP and MQ. MP’s
>   parameter types are more specific than
>   MQ’s if, for each parameter, RX is not
>   less specific than SX, and, for at
>   least one parameter, RX is more
>   specific than SX:specific than SX:
>
> - A type parameter is less specific than a non-type parameter.
> - ...

So even though the *conversion* is equally good, the overload using `IfaceA` directly (rather than via delegates) is deemed "better" because a parameter of type `IfaceA` is more specific than a parameter of type `T`.

There's no way of getting the compiler to warn on this behaviour - it's just normal overload resolution.

Comment: Ok thanks a million. I guess that means I will read that specification. I am just a Java convert and have to use C# for this project. Although in fact I think its more useful, but any feature I feel adds also some edge cases more ...

Answer (score 1):

Because the compiler chooses the most specific first.

What happens if you call like so:

```
void code()   
{ 
    var concreteB = new ConcreteB(); 

    IfaceA  x = concreteB.Add(new ConcreteA()); 
}
```

Comment: But why would `void Add(IfaceA a)` be any more specific? Is it because I do not use the returned result? And besides, do you know if I there is a compiler option to yield me a warning?

Comment: @sebgod: you can use the `#warning` directive to issue a compiler warning.

Comment: The code will not compile if i choose `IfaceA  x = concreteB.Add(new ConcreteA());` : cannot implicitly convert between IFaceA and void

Comment: it looks like the compiler kind of does only consider the interface based method and does not check the generic overload, btw, what does "one for the Skeet" mean?

Comment: As you see this is my first question on SO, I'm sad I cannot vote up your answer, says I need 15 points, I think this morning the coffee wasn't good ^^

Comment: @Mitch: I was busy typing it up :)

Comment: @Tomas, with warning I mean that the compiler would tell me about it, not I want to issue the warning (this was all a silent code break)

Answer (score 1):

This somewhat reminds me of the "Type inference a-go-go" in [Jon Skeet's BrainTeaser](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/teasers.html).
If you do not want to trust the compiler, you might want to force its choice by calling `Add<ConcreteA>(new ConcreteA())`

Comment: Thats what my teacher always told me, never trust your compiler